# Getting error with createBrowserRouter: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to switch from BrowserRoute component to createBrowserRouter in React Router 6.4.3 but getting error:

> useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a  component.

How can I fix that? The error comes from AuthProvider component and I think I need to wrap it with RouterProvider but its not clear how I can do that.

**Index.tsx component**

```
const container = document.getElementById('root')!;
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AuthProvider>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <App />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </AuthProvider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.tsx component**

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <ProtectedRoute />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <DashboardLayout />,
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <HomePage />,
          },
          {
            path: 'about',
            element: <AboutPage />,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/auth',
    element: <Auth />,
  },
]);

const App = () => {
  const { isLoading } = useAuth0();

  if (isLoading) {
    return <LoaderPage />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Box>
        <CssBaseline />
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Error comes from AuthProvider.tsx**

```
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<Auth0ProviderWithConfigProps>): JSX.Element | null => {
  const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
  const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  if (!(domain && clientId)) {
    return null;
  }

  const onRedirectCallback = (appState: any) => {
    navigate(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
  };

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      redirectUri={window.location.origin}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};
```

**UPD**

**ProtectedRoute.tsx**

```
export const ProtectedRoute: React.FC = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

  return isAuthenticated? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/auth" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
};
```

If I rollback, change these components to back BrowserRouter then everyting works:

**index.tsx**

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <App />
          </ThemeProvider>
        </Provider>
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.tsx**

```
const App = () => {
  const { isLoading } = useAuth0();

  const routes = useRoutes([
    {
      element: <ProtectedRoute />,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/',
          element: <DashboardLayout />,
          children: [
            {
              index: true,
              element: <HomePage />,
            },
            {
              path: 'about',
              element: <AboutPage />,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: '/auth',
      element: <Auth />,
    },
  ]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <LoaderPage />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Box>
        <CssBaseline />
        {routes}
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Codesandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-morning-oxwwj6?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: The Provider wrapper should be inside the Router wrapper ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AuthProvider` component needs to be rendered within the routing context in order to access it and use any of the `react-router-dom` hooks. Create a layout route that renders the `AuthProvider` wrapping an `Outlet` component.

Example:

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  Outlet
} from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthLayout = () => (
  <AuthProvider>
    <Outlet />
  </AuthProvider>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AuthLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        element: <ProtectedRoute />,
        children: [
          {
            path: '/',
            element: <DashboardLayout />,
            children: [
              {
                index: true,
                element: <HomePage />,
              },
              {
                path: 'about',
                element: <AboutPage />,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: '/auth',
        element: <Auth />,
      },
    ]
  },
]);

const App = () => {
  const { isLoading } = useAuth0();

  if (isLoading) {
    return <LoaderPage />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Box>
        <CssBaseline />
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```

...

```
const container = document.getElementById('root')!;
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <App />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: the error associated with useNavigation has gone...but app still doesn't work...now isLoading state doesn't changes at all. It always true and isAuthenticated is always false...I added UPD with code of ProtectedRoute.tsx ..can you take a look please?

Comment: @qweezz Similar to the `useNavigate` hook needing to be rendered within a routing context, so too does the `useAuth0` hook need to be used within the Auth0 context provided by the `AuthProvider` component. Here's a fork of your [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/getting-error-with-createbrowserrouter-usenavigate-may-be-used-only-in-the-co-5qy25r) with a small refactor to do this.