# Render a component and use useNavigate inside it without routing it

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navigation, react-router-dom, cart

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  Outlet,
  RouterProvider,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Cart from './components/Cart';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
>! routes on my app
]);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Suspense
        fallback={
          <div className="w-screen h-screen flex justify-center bg-gray-300 opacity-70 backdrop-blur-md items-center">
            <svg
              className="animate-spin h-half w-half  ..."
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            ></svg>
          </div>
        }
      >
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
        <Cart />
      </Suspense>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Cart Component

```
`export default function Cart({navigate}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cartOpen = useSelector((state) => state.user.cartOpen);
  const loading = useSelector((state) => state.user.loading);

  const cartProducts = useSelector(
    (state) => state.user.cartProducts,
  );

  const sumTotal = cartProducts.reduce(
    (accumulator, product) => accumulator + product.total,
    0,
  );

  return (
    <main
      className={`fixed z-[99999] bg-white h-full w-1/3 flex flex-col shadow-xl  gap-5 transition-all duration-1000 ease-in-out overflow-y-scroll snap ${
        cartOpen ? 'right-0 top-0' : 'top-0 right-[-300%]'
      } px-5 py-8 lato`}
    >
      <div className="flex justify-between items-center w-full h-fit">
        <h3 className="text-3xl md:text-[25px] font-[500] corm">
          My Cart
        </h3>
        <button
          onClick={() => dispatch(setCartOpen(false))}
          className="text-2xl hover:text-primary"
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClose} />
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col divide-y-[3px]">
        {cartProducts.map((cartProduct, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <CartProduct
              name={cartProduct.name}
              price={cartProduct.total}
              img={cartProduct.img}
              quantity={cartProduct.quantity}
              total={cartProduct.total}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="py-4 border-y-[3px] flex justify-between items-center">
        <p>SUBTOTAL</p>
        <p>{sumTotal}</p>
      </div>
      <p className="text-primary underline">Add a Gift Message</p>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 justify-center items-center">
        <p>Taxes and Shipping will be calculated at checkout</p>
        <button
          className={`w-full text-white text-[18px] bg-primary font-[600] md:px-16 py-2 ${
            loading ? 'animate-pulse duration-500' : ''
          } `}
          disabled={loading}
        >
          CHECKOUT
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3 className="text-2xl md:text-[25px] font-[500] corm">
          My Cart
        </h3>
        <p>
          <button
            className="inline underline"
            onClick={() => {
              setCartOpen(false);
              navigate('/login');
            }}
          >
            Log In{' '}
          </button>
          to check out faster.
        </p>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}`
```

My problem is that i am trying to use UseNavigate inside the Cart component which is outside the router, so my page isnt rendering..
Is there a way to work around this or put the cart in the createBrowserRouter but not with a path as i am rendering as a side bar that comes up conditionally.

Comment: I'm not a fun of this solution but take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74443583/getting-error-with-createbrowserrouter-usenavigate-may-be-used-only-in-the-co

Comment: Just put the router context higher up the tree?

Comment: @JacobSmit how do u suggest i do that?

Comment: Well it depends what the rest of your code looks like, but if the cart is to be on every single route (like it is currently) create a `BaseLayout` component (or whatever you want to call it) put the `Cart` component and an `Outlet` component (from react-router) in it. Then make the initial route (that all other routes are children) use the `BaseLayout` component.